# Issue with document.getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, html

I am using it to show an item that needs to stay hidden until I click on a button to display it, the thing is that it does what It's meant to be doing but still shows an error on the console. Here is the code that I am using.

```
    <button onclick="MostrarPuntaje()">Mostrar Puntajes</button>
```

and the Javascript function that is called by the button:

```
    function MostrarPuntaje(){

var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('puntaje');
for(var i = 0; i!=elements.lenght; i++){
    elements[i].style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

Finally, this is the error the console is showing, even tho it really displays the items that were hidden.

tablero.html:53 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

The line 53 is the following (It is inside the for loop):

```
elements[i].style.visibility = 'visible';
```

I hope you could understand my code and my words since I can't seem to find a proper way to explain this mistake, I honestly don't know what I'm doing wrong, thanks for reading and I hope you can help me.

Comment: `i!=elements.lenght` (typo on `length`?) what are you doing not equals, versus `<=` for? Let's assume `length` is 5. The style will only trigger when `i` is 5, and that's outside the bounds since arrays, NodeLists, etc index at 0.

Comment: this id an infinite loop waiting to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of typo. Inside for loop change the condition to `elements.length` instead of `elements.lenght`.

**Why it works**

The for loop condition, `i!=elements.lenght` will be interpreted as `i!= undefined` and the condition is always true since the index starts from 0 and increases on.

So `elements[0]` works well. And then it'll move to the next step `elements[1]` which is undefined and it throws error since we are accessing the style property of undefined

Comment: It's not safe to assume this since the error proceeds past it. Also, if the question is a typo, please close it as such.

Comment: @Sterling Archer.. there was no assumption made. It's clear that the condition of for loop is never ending and when we try to access the second index we'll get this error. I don't see anything wrong with this answer. Though it's a typo I thought it needed an explanation why it worked..

Comment: Thank you very much DRB, English is not my mother language and I usually mix th with ht, sorry. It solved the problem.